# sklearn pipeline raises ValueError after imputer, but running each component does not raise error

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

I was trying to setup a pipeline with the following code. temp_start, and temp are both pandas DataFrames.

```
imp = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.NaN,strategy='mean')

linreg = LinearRegression()
steps = [('imputation', imp),('linear_regression', linreg)]
pipeline = Pipeline(steps)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(temp_start, temp,test_size=0.3, random_state=42)
pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Which raises `ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').`

However, when I run each component of this pipeline, it runs perfectly. I used the code below.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(temp_start, temp, test_size=0.3, 
random_state=42)

X_train = imp.fit_transform(X_train)
y_train = imp.fit_transform(y_train)
X_test = imp.fit_transform(X_test)
y_test = imp.fit_transform(y_test)

model = LinearRegression().fit(X_train,y_train)
model.score(X_test, y_test)
```

I can't figure out why one runs and the other does not.